# Rewrite JwkThumbprint getter function from node-jose to C#

Tags: c#, node.js, cryptography, bouncycastle, node-jose

There is a function in `NodeJs` that, using `node-jose`, gets a thumbprint from a certificate.

```
const jose = require('node-jose');

generateJwkThumbprint = async (jwk) => {
  let jwkKey = await jose.JWK.asKey(jwk, 'pem'); //convert pem to jwk
  let jwkThumbprintBuffer = await jwkKey.thumbprint('SHA-256'); // sha256 has of the jwk object
  let jwkThumbprint = jose.util.base64url.encode(jwkThumbprintBuffer, 'utf8'); // base64 urlencode of the hash

  return jwkThumbprint;
};


let publicKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEZ1fr5JeX52k397Eex4oDBwODEOwz\nBG5qGAfmBFSz4aRZkqJeMPq5pV6jhaPN/w9wvTYNc0ibT8129/GCag6Snw==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";

(async () => {
    try {
      let thumbprint = await generateJwkThumbprint(publicKey);
      console.log(thumbprint);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    }
  })();
```

Code above works fine in `NodeJs`.
[image]

I tried to get a thumbprint in `C#` using the `BouncyCastl` library:

```
static void Main()
{
    var publicKey =
        "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEZ1fr5JeX52k397Eex4oDBwODEOwz\nBG5qGAfmBFSz4aRZkqJeMPq5pV6jhaPN/w9wvTYNc0ibT8129/GCag6Snw==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";

    var thumbprint = GenerateJwkThumbprint(publicKey);

    Console.Write(thumbprint);
}

private static AsymmetricKeyParameter JwkPemToAsymmetricKey(string jwkPem)
{
    using StringReader reader = new StringReader(jwkPem);
    var pemReader = new PemReader(reader);
    var keyObject = pemReader.ReadObject();

    if (keyObject is ECPublicKeyParameters ecPublicKey)
    {
        return ecPublicKey;
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid JWK PEM format or unsupported key type.");
}

private static string GenerateJwkThumbprint(string jwkPem)
{
    // Convert PEM to JWK
    var jwkKey = JwkPemToAsymmetricKey(jwkPem);

    // Calculate SHA-256 thumbprint
    var sha256Thumbprint = CalculateSha256Thumbprint(jwkKey);

    // Base64url encode the thumbprint
    var thumbprint = Base64UrlEncode(sha256Thumbprint);

    return thumbprint;
}

private static string Base64UrlEncode(byte[] bytes)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes).Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_').Replace("=", "");
}

private static byte[] CalculateSha256Thumbprint(AsymmetricKeyParameter jwkKey)
{
    IDigest digest = new Sha256Digest();
    var jwkBytes = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(jwkKey).GetDerEncoded();
    digest.BlockUpdate(jwkBytes, 0, jwkBytes.Length);
    var thumbprint = new byte[digest.GetDigestSize()];
    digest.DoFinal(thumbprint, 0);
    return thumbprint;
}
```

But in the end I get different thumbprints in `C#` and `NodeJs`.
[image]

So in conclusion:

#### NodeJs

```js
thumbprint = "Mts1dD5R6PnYesvL0YLbc43h4YBVrd8_koC9jFsv_Sg"
```

#### C#

```cs
thumbprint = 'yLCIQ8WauQaPAC4A3-LQ5l5s_p9vRfOqPl10efd0hck'
```

They are different, why is that?

Comment: The C# code generates the SHA256 hash of the DER-encoded public key in X.509/SPKI format (`jwkBytes`). However, the JWK thumbprint is based on a key in JWK format. To achieve this, a JWT library is (presumably) more suitable than BouncyCastle. An alternative to the Chilkat package for creating the JWK thumbprint is the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens package.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the [ChilkatDnCore](https://www.example-code.com/mono/jwk_public_key_thumbprint.asp) package

C# code:

```
static void Main()
{
    var publicKey =
        "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEZ1fr5JeX52k397Eex4oDBwODEOwz\nBG5qGAfmBFSz4aRZkqJeMPq5pV6jhaPN/w9wvTYNc0ibT8129/GCag6Snw==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";
    Chilkat.PublicKey pubKey = new Chilkat.PublicKey();

    pubKey.LoadFromString(publicKey);

    var thumbprint = pubKey.GetJwkThumbprint("SHA256");

    Console.Write(thumbprint);
}
```